# Custom "mouse" gestures for Trackpad on Macbook Pro and Magic mouse

Tags: macbook-pro, mouse, trackpad, multi-touch

Is it possible to create custom gestures for Macbook Pro Trackpad and Magic Mouse to custom actions? For example to close a window or launch some application.

Comment: How customized do you want? My popular apps are all custom-swipe-launchable: Swipe to dock on right, the adjust vertically, then click :).

Comment: @mankoff: the ones I'd like to have the most are hide/close/quit gestures, since that's what's making me touch the keyboard

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not so sure about the Magic Mouse, but for the trackpad there are a number of options.

[**jitouch**](http://www.jitouch.com/index.php?page=jitouch) looks very customisable, but costs.

[**BetterTouchTool**](http://boastr.net/) works with the Magic Mouse. It gives you a PrefPane that lets you assign loads of gestures with loads of actions, including opening Apps. I'm sure it has capability to close windows as well.

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1 for BetterTouchTool. It allowed me to create some unusual gestures (rotate left and right, for example) that save time every day.

Answer (score 1):

Another useful tool is [MagicPrefs](http://magicprefs.com/), although it really shines with the trackpad.